# Azure SQL server Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY/ANONYMOUS LOGIN'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I'm trying to log into an Azure SQL server from SSMS using my Azure active directory account.
I've followed this guide: [Configure and manage Azure Active Directory authentication with SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure)

I've added my account as an admin:
[image]

And my account also shows up as the Active Directory admin in the properties of the SQL database:

[image]

Then, I try to log in with SSMS, with Active Directory authentication:
[image]

I login with my account and get the MFA notification, but after that I get the following error:
[image]

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: Can you try again with Active Directory-Password authentication? Still get the same error? Please show the error details.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the db name in `Options` -> `Connection Properties`?

Comment: @LeonYue: I tried this but get a message that MFA is required.

Comment: @Turbo: I tried this as well but get the same error

Comment: @BartvanderDrift which SSMS version you are using? If you are using SSMS 17.9, try specifying the db name and  set AD domain in  `Options` -> `Connection Properties`.

Comment: @LeonYue: That fixed it! Specifying the AD domain did the trick. Can you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @BartvanderDrift ok, congratulations!

Comment: @BartvanderDrift I have post it to my answer, you can accept and mark it know. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which SSMS version you are using?

If you are using SSMS 17.9, try specifying the db name and set AD domain in `Options` -> `Connection Properties`.

[image]

Congratulations that the error have be solved by this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be related to the Active Directory AD Syncing options. Maybe in your environment AD is not syncing passwords into the tenant. This prevents AD Integration Authentication, AD Universal Authentication with MFA and AD Password Authentication. The only authentication that works in this instance is AD Universal Authentication (no MFA).