# Azure SQL Server Cannot Be Accessed With Active Directory Authentication

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

My organization has an Azure tenant. The tenant has three subscriptions. Each subscription has multiple Azure SQL Servers. On two of the subscriptions, the databases can be accessed via one of the Active Directory authentication methods. On the third subscription, the only method of access is via SQL Server Authentication. I am the owner of this third subscription.

If I configure an Active Directory Admin for the Server, the error I receive is:

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)
```

When I remove the Active Directory Admin for the Server, the error I receive is:

```
Requested tenant identifier '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' is not valid. Tenant identifiers may not be an empty GUID.
```

How do I change this so that the SQL Servers can be accessed via Active Directory authentication? What is the best approach to determine the the differences between the subscription at issue and the other two subscriptions?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you added the AAD Admin, that's the AAD account you tried to log in as?

Comment: Yes, I tried logging in as the AAD admin, and under an account that only has user privileges. Same result.

Comment: Your Active Directory Admin is different from other two subscriptions, am I right? Can this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57588974/10549281 be help?

Comment: Leon, I had read that question before posting mine, and found that explicitly entering the tenant ID made no difference. When I run Get-AzureRMSubscription from the Azure Cloud Shell command line, it states that all three subscriptions are part of the same tenant.

Comment: Hi @RSax, any progress now?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue, you need to set Active Directory Admin for the SQL Server (Settings -> Active Directory Admin).